# How to grep '$$$$$'?

Tags: grep, string, search, special-characters, file-search

I want to check the absence of the following sequence of characters `$$$$$` (i.e., 5 dollar signs) in a `json` file using `grep` as it has been used instead of comma to separate fields and I need to make sure this did not cause conflicts with existing similar sequence.

However, when I grep `$`, I get similar number of lines. It seems that `$` is a special character for end of line?

How can i search for `$$$$$` using grep?
Is `$` a special character?

Comment: In addition, in _shell_ unquoted `$$` is a special parameter which is replaced by the PID of the shell; this is commonly (and traditionally) used to create unique/nonconflicting names for temp-files and such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> It seems that `$` is a special character for end of line?

Yep, exactly. And there's an end-of-line on each and every line.

You'll need to use `\$\$\$\$\$` as the pattern, or use `grep -F '$$$$$'`, to tell `grep` to use the pattern as a fixed string instead of a regular expression.

Or a shorter version regex pattern: `\$\{5\}` in basic regex or `\${5}` in extended regular expressions (`grep -E`).

<sub>(In basic regular expressions (plain `grep`), you really only need to escape the last dollar sign, so `$$$$\$` would do instead of `\$\$\$\$\$`. But in extended (`grep -E`) and Perl regular expressions they all need to be escaped so better do that anyway.)</sub>